# Merging Sorted Lists with Iterators in Java

Tags: java, list, merge, iterator

The method I am using takes two sorted lists and returns a single list containing all of the elements in the two original lists, in sorted order.

For example, if the original lists are (1, 4, 5) and (2, 3, 6) then the result list would be (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

Is there something I am missing?

```
public static<E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> mergeSortedLists(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();

    PushbackIterator<E> aIter = new PushbackIterator<E>(a.iterator());
    PushbackIterator<E> bIter = new PushbackIterator<E>(b.iterator());

    while (aIter.hasNext() && bIter.hasNext()) {
        if (aIter.next().compareTo(bIter.next()) < 0) {
            result.add(aIter.next());
        }  
        if (bIter.next().compareTo(bIter.next()) > 0){
            result.add(bIter.next());
        }
    }
    while (aIter.hasNext()) {
        result.add(aIter.next());
    }
    while (bIter.hasNext()) {
        result.add(bIter.next());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because of so many reasons.  For instance, you are calling `next()` twice for a given step.

Comment: Did you forget why you're using a `PushbackIterator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you intended something like this with your use of `PushbackIterator`:

```
while (aIter.hasNext() && bIter.hasNext()) {
    E aElem = aIter.next();
    E bElem = bIter.next();
    if (aElem.compareTo(bElem) <= 0) {
        result.add(aElem);
        bIter.pushback(bElem);
    } else {
        result.add(bElem);
        aIter.pushback(aElem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform a merge, you need to peek at the next value, so see which next value to use.

Eventually, one of the lists will run out of values before the other, so you need to check for that.

One trick is to use `null` as an End-Of-Data marker, assuming that lists cannot contain `null` values, which is a fair assumption since they have to be sorted. In that case, code will be like this:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> mergeSortedLists(List<E> list1, List<E> list2) {
    List<E> merged = new ArrayList<>(list1.size() + list2.size());

    // Get list iterators and fetch first value from each, if available
    Iterator<E> iter1 = list1.iterator();
    Iterator<E> iter2 = list2.iterator();
    E value1 = (iter1.hasNext() ? iter1.next() : null);
    E value2 = (iter2.hasNext() ? iter2.next() : null);

    // Loop while values remain in either list
    while (value1 != null || value2 != null) {

        // Choose list to pull value from
        if (value2 == null || (value1 != null && value1.compareTo(value2) <= 0)) {

            // Add list1 value to result and fetch next value, if available
            merged.add(value1);
            value1 = (iter1.hasNext() ? iter1.next() : null);

        } else {

            // Add list2 value to result and fetch next value, if available
            merged.add(value2);
            value2 = (iter2.hasNext() ? iter2.next() : null);

        }
    }

    // Return merged result
    return merged;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(mergeSortedLists(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 5),
                                    Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6)));
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I was looking for a pure Java way to merge two sorted iterators and your answer has been the best solution I have found as yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a library, the cleanest solution would be to use Collection-utils4 and *IteratorUtils.collatedIterator()*.

You need to provide a *Comparator* in order to pick the right element.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach of merging 2 arrays can also be used with iterators tweaking a little bit. you can use adding elements instead of printing if needed.

```
static void printItr(Iterator<String> it1, Iterator<String> it2) {
    String firstString=null,secondString = null;
    boolean moveAheadIt1 = true, moveAheadIt2 = true;

    while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()){
         firstString = moveAheadIt1 ? it1.next() : firstString ;
         secondString = moveAheadIt2 ? it2.next() : secondString;

         if(firstString.compareTo(secondString) < 0){
            System.out.println(firstString);
            moveAheadIt2 = false;
            moveAheadIt1 = true;
        }else {
            System.out.println(secondString);
            moveAheadIt1 = false;
            moveAheadIt2 = true;
        }
    }

    while(it1.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it1.next());
    }
    while(it2.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it2.next());
    }

}
```